# How to loop through a huge json with same key names

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have a huge json file with following structure:

```
    name: 'xxx',
    worth: [123, 456, 789]
    children: [
       {name: 'xxx',
       worth: [987, 654, 321],
       children: [
          {name: 'xxx',
          worth: [213, 546, 879],
          children: []}
       },
       {name: 'xxx',
       worth: [987, 654, 321],
       children: [
          name: 'xxx',
          worth: [213, 546, 879],
          children: []
       }],
    ]
```

The number of children can get up to 10 layer deep.
I created an angular component that displays name and worth and takes children as an Input to call itself again with the children's name and worth but I get maximum stack size errors with this approach.

How to write a function that can loop through this json until children array is empty and display the name and worth of all of them on the way?
This screams recursion but I cant manage...

Comment: Show the angular component...

Comment: What should be the expected output exactly?

Comment: I actually want to list all of name, worth and children until no children appear anymore.

Comment: Something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-d3y5tm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming your root object represents a single child, your code would look like this:

```
const child = {
  name: "xxx1",
  worth: [123, 456, 789],
  children: [
    {
      name: "xxx2",
      worth: [987, 654, 321],
      children: [
        {
          name: "xxx3",
          worth: [213, 546, 879],
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "xxx4",
      worth: [987, 654, 321],
      children: [
        {
          name: "xxx5",
          worth: [213, 546, 879],
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const sum = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

function process_child(child, result) {
  const { name, worth, children } = child;
  result.push({ name, worth: sum(worth) });

  for (const c of children) {
    process_child(c, result);
  }

  return result;
}

const children = process_child(child, []);
console.table(children);
```

Here, `process_child` is a function that takes in a single `child` and a list of results (initially empty). It populates the list of results while going through all the nested children. The end result is an array of objects with the structure `{name, worth}`, which you can then consume in whatever way you wish.

This is not an Angular-specific problem, and in fact you will just want your Angular component to be a passive consumer of the data returned by this function.

Here's a working execution on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-68627995-zwt7q?file=/src/index.js) where the result is simply displayed on the page in JSON form.